# How to resolve this cyclic include?

Tags: c++, templates, typedef

I came across this kind of situation but could not resolve, any hint would be greatly appreciated

```
//in file Common.h
#ifndef _COMMON_H_
#define _COMMON_H_
#include "Node.h"
template <typename T>
struct Ptr
{ 
     typedef std::tr1::shared_ptr< Node<T> >   NodeSPtr;
};
#endif

// in file Node.h
#ifndef _NODE_H_
#define _NODE_H_
#include "common.h"
template < typename T >
class Node
{
   T data; 
   Ptr<T>::NodeSPtr next;
};
#endif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a combination of forward declaration and `typename`. Also, the include guards would not be amiss ;)

Node.h:

```
#ifndef Node_h
#define Node_h

template <typename T> struct Ptr;

template <typename T>
class Node {
   T data; 
   typename Ptr<T>::NodeSPtr next;
};

#endif
```

Common.h:

```
#ifndef Common_h
#define Common_h

#include <memory>

template <typename T> class Node;

template <typename T>
struct Ptr { 
    typedef std::shared_ptr< Node<T> > NodeSPtr;
};

#endif
```

You can now include these headers in any order and multiple times.

Comment: @AayushPoudel Hmm... if it helped, you should accept it. Or, if some other answer helped more, you should accept that other answer. In any case, you should show your appreciation for the other people's efforts to help you, by upvoting (when your reputation reaches 15) and accepting helpful answers.

Answer (score 3):

An egg and a chicken problem. :)

Note declaration of Node in Common.h

```
//in file Common.h

template <typename T>
class Node;

template <typename T>
struct Ptr
{ 
     typedef std::tr1::shared_ptr< Node<T> >   NodeSPtr;
};

// in file Node.h
#include "common.h"
template < typename T >
class Node
{
   T data; 
   Ptr<T>::NodeSPtr next;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

As long as you don't access the `NodeSPtr` pointee in a manner that requires knowing the size of `Node`, you may merely *declare* `Node` in Common.h.

Also, it's okay to say `std::shared_ptr`, as opposed to `std::tr1::shared_ptr`.

Answer (score 0):

I would:

```
//in file Common.h
#include "Node.h"
template <typename T>
struct Ptr
{ 
   typedef Node::NodeSPtr   NodeSPtr;
};

// in file Node.h
template < typename T >
class Node
{
   T data; 
   typedef std::tr1::shared_ptr< Node<T> >   NodeSPtr;
   NodeSPtr next;
};
```